# Turn subquery result to array in Kylin

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, kylin

How can I turn the result from subquery into an array in Kylin? In PostgresSQL, I can do it like the query below, but in Kylin it is an error.

```
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT A.ID
    FROM A
    WHERE A.num = 123
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked [Kylin SQL reference](https://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/sql_reference.html), there is no such ARRAY function or similar. Seems the feature you are looking for is not in Kylin yet.